# MySQL select songs from ids in other table

Tags: php, mysql, select

How can i select all the id's from a table, and let select all the songs with the id;s from the other table?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = (SELECT songid FROM top10 order by id)'";
```

Comment: And how can i order it by the ids in the table top10?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IN` for that (or `EXISTS`):

```
select * 
from songs
where id in (
    select songid 
    from top10 )
```

---

Based on your comments, you might actually be looking to use `JOIN` (just realize if there are duplicate records in the top10 table, this could return duplicate results):

```
select s.* 
from songs s
 join top10 t on s.id = t.songid
order by t.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05ae0/2)

Comment: how can i order it by the id from top10

Comment: @niekotje - Perhaps you need to use join -- take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05ae0/2